# Formatting External tables in Greenplum (PostgreSQL)

Tags: database, postgresql, greenplum

I want to load a plain file into Greenplum database using external tables. 
Can I specify input format for timestamps/date/time fields? (If you know the answer for PostgreSQL, please reply as well)

For example, with Oracle I can use DATE_FORMAT DATE MASK 'YYYYMMDD' to tell how to parse the date. For Netezza I can specify DATESTYLE 'YMD'. For Greenplum I cannot find the answer. I can describe fields as char, and then parse them during the load, but this is an ugly workaround.

Here is my tentative code:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE MY_TBL (X date, Y time, Z timestamp ) 
LOCATION (
 'gpfdist://host:8001/file1.txt',
 'gpfdist://host:8002/file2.txt'
) FORMAT 'TEXT' (DELIMITER '|' NULL '')
```

Comment: You an `SET DATESTYLE = 'YMD';` before loading CSV with `COPY`, but I'm not sure about external tables. Good point. Is the `DATESTYLE` in effect at the time of the external table's creation preserved? What happens if you change it after creating the external table?

Comment: SET DATESTYLE does apply for reading from external tables too. That helps! Thank you.  It applies during select (after table is created). It looks like this is the only way to control formats - control them globally. -- could you post it as an answer, please?

Comment: This doesn't really apply to PostgreSQL proper, by the way. In PostgreSQL you would use the `file_fdw` foreign data wrapper (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/file-fdw.html), as there is no `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you can:

```
SET DATESTYLE = 'YMD';
```

before `SELECT`ing from the table. This will affect the interpretation of all dates, though, not just those from the file. If you consistently use unambiguous ISO dates elsewhere that will be fine, but it may be a problem if (for example) you need to also accept 'D/M/Y' date literals in the same query.

This is specific to GreenPlum's `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE` and does not apply to SQL-standard `SQL/MED` foreign data wrappers, as shown below.

---

What surprises me is that PostgreSQL proper (which does not have this `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE` feature) *always* accepts ISO-style `YYYY-MM-DD` and `YYYYMMDD` dates, irrespective of `DATESTYLE`. Observe:

```
regress=> SELECT '20121229'::date, '2012-12-29'::date, current_setting('DateStyle');
    date    |    date    | current_setting 
------------+------------+-----------------
 2012-12-29 | 2012-12-29 | ISO, MDY
(1 row)

regress=> SET DateStyle = 'DMY';
SET
regress=> SELECT '20121229'::date, '2012-12-29'::date, current_setting('DateStyle');
    date    |    date    | current_setting 
------------+------------+-----------------
 2012-12-29 | 2012-12-29 | ISO, DMY
(1 row)
```

... so if GreenPlum behaved the same way, you should not need to do anything to get these `YYYYMMDD` dates to be read correctly from the input file.

Here's how it works with a PostgreSQL [`file_fdw` `SQL/MED` foreign data wrapper](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/file-fdw.html):

```
CREATE EXTENSION file_fdw;

COPY (SELECT '20121229', '2012-12-29') TO '/tmp/dates.csv' CSV;

SET DateStyle = 'DMY';

CREATE SERVER csvtest FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER file_fdw;

CREATE FOREIGN TABLE csvtest (
    date1 date,
    date2 date
) SERVER csvtest OPTIONS ( filename '/tmp/dates.csv', format 'csv' );

SELECT * FROM csvtest ;
   date1    |   date2    
------------+------------
 2012-12-29 | 2012-12-29
(1 row)
```

The CSV file contents are:

```
20121229,2012-12-29
```

so you can see that Pg will always accept ISO dates for CSV, irrespective of datestyle.

If GreenPlum doesn't, please file a bug. The idea of `DateStyle` changing the way a foreign table is read after creation is crazy.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

You do this by specifying the field in the external table to be of type text.  Then, use a transformation in the insert statement.  You can also use gpload and define the transformation.  Both solutions are similar to the solution described above.

Here is a simple file with an integer and a date expressed as year month day, separated by a space:

date1.txt

```
1|2012 10 12
2|2012 11 13
```

Start gpfdist:

```
gpfdist -p 8010 -d ./ -l ./gpfdist.log &
```

Use psql to create the external table, the target table, and load the data:

```
psql test

test=# create external table ext.t2( i int, d text ) 
  location ('gpfdist://walstl-mbp.local:8010/date1.txt') 
  format 'TEXT' ( delimiter '|' )
;


test=# select * from ext.t2; i |     d      
---+------------
  1 | 2012 10 12
  2 | 2012 11 13
(2 rows)
```

Now, create the table that the data will be loaded into:

```
test=# create table test.t2 ( i int, d date ) 
;
```

And,load the table:

```
test=# insert into test.t2 select i, to_date(d,'YYYY MM DD') from ext.t2 ;

test=# select * from test.t2;
 i |     d      
---+------------
 1 | 2012-10-12
 2 | 2012-11-13
```

Comment: I pointed in my question that there is a way to define fields as char, and then parse them during the load - but it is a workaround which may be undesired (for example, my utility creates external table and user code is responsible for loading from it into a permanent table). You cannot specify 'DISTRIBUTED BY' for external tables, only for internal tables - this option tells Greenplum how to bucket your table during the load into persistent (internal) table.

Comment: You also can specify DISTRIBUTED BY for writable external tables, but not for tables used for reading (as I used them)